# systemctl start not returning/exiting

Tags: redis, systemd

I'm trying to start a service file for redis, I've read many posts about running it as a systemd service and I'm not sure why this is happening.

When I run
`sudo systemctl start redis-server.service`
it doesn't return/exit - just sits there with the cursor flashing until I Ctrl-C. I've confirmed the server is up and running so the server seems to be working fine - I'm not sure why systemctl start never exits. Redis is meant to work with systemd and with the argument --supervised systemd the service should be Type=notify.

My service file is:

```
[Unit]
Description=Redis

[Service]
Type=notify
User=john
Group=john
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/redis-server /home/john/redis/redis.conf --supervised systemd --daemonize no
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/redis-cli shutdown
Restart=on-success
WorkingDirectory=/home/john/redis

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The contents of redis.conf is:

```
port              6379
save              60 1
bind              127.0.0.1
tcp-keepalive     300
dbfilename        dump.rdb
dir               ./
logfile           ./redis-server.log
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems from version 6 of redis it needs to be compiled with the `libsystemd-dev` package installed on Ubuntu + Debian. See this GitHub issue: https://github.com/redis/redis/issues/7284.

Installing this package and recompiling redis fixed the issue.

Comment: Apparently it checks existence of `libsystemd` using `pkg-config` and I didn't have it on my Ubuntu Server 20.04 installation so do `apt install pkg-config` before recompiling if you don't have `pkg-config` installed.